# When running GCC/G++, how to tell it where it was installed

Tags: c++, gcc

Let's say I did this while installing GCC (on RHEL6):

```
./configure --prefix=/path/to/gcc_install
make
make install
```

Then I move it:

```
mv /path/to/gcc_install /other/path/to/gcc
```

Then I set my `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` correctly... **How do I tell it where to find the STL headers & STD C++ library that it installed so it doesn't look in /usr/...?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word to describe this property is "relocatable".  That means the program and its support files can be moved after it is built and it will still be able to find everything it needs.

From [this thread](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2011-01/msg00384.html), it sounds like GCC is already relocatable by default since it uses relative paths to find all of its files.  If you continue to have trouble, I suggest posting a shell session showing how you compiled, installed, and ran GCC, and then showing how it doesn't work when you move it to a different folder.  You should run GCC with the `-v` option so we can see detailed information about what it is doing.

Comment: I didn't know gcc/g++ would use its path and relative paths from it to find its installed stuff. This was a question preemptive to an actual issue because *obviously* I have to tell it exactly how things should work.

Comment: I didn't know that either, and I have no direct experience with it.  The thread on the mailing list could be wrong.